# Object Reference Not Set to an Instance - Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this simple code to change the `sprite` of an `image` everytime I click a button.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SampleChange : MonoBehaviour {

public Sprite sampleSprite;
public Image sampleImage;

public void Start()
{
    sampleImage = GetComponent<Image>();
}

public void changeColor()
{
    sampleImage.gameObject.GetComponent<Image>();
    sampleImage.sprite = sampleSprite;
}

}
```

I attached this script to an `EmptyGameObject` and Loaded the function on the `Button` that is parented on a `Canvas` alongside the `Image`. I already also placed the `Image` and `Sprite` objects in the inspector:

[Inspector Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9MiR.png)

When I run the game and click the `Button`, it gives me this error:

`NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
SampleChange.changeColor () (at Assets/Scripts/SampleChange.cs:18)`

The `cs:18` is the `sampleImage.sprite = sampleSprite;`. I really don't know why it's not working.

Comment: Remove the `sampleImage = GetComponent<Image>();` code since it looks like you're already setting it from the Editor. Also remove `sampleImage.gameObject.GetComponent<Image>();`. You are not setting the value it is returning to anything...

Comment: Lol listen to Programmer  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK simple,

```
 public Image sampleImage;
```

that means

## you will set "sampleImage" variable in the inspector, in the editor, before you hit Play

But this one ..

```
 sampleImage = GetComponent<Image>();
```

means

## you will set "sampleImage" variable in code when the scene is running.

You have to sort it out and do it "one way or the other".

Suggest you use the first method while U learning.

(If you *do* use the second method, the "Image" must actually be on the game object which is holding the script in question.  If you struggle with that, I would urge you to ask a separate question, or just study up on the basics using Unity tutorials.)

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

It appears that you have no constuctor defined for your class and that you are just trying to call the `changeColor()` method as if it were a static function of the class. You need to construct objects of your class and then call the methods you defined on those objects, not on the class itself.

Comment: Brian, that is not relevant here - it's a MonoBehavior which is a specific Unity thing, and that's how you make calls on such Components.